# Win32 API - CurrentWindow to Message-Only-Window and back to original window

Tags: windows, winapi

I use SetParent to change a window to a message-only window however when I attempt to use SetParent to restore the window I either don't get the window back or a massive delay? Example source code.

```
// Change to message-only

HWND newParent = SetParent(currentHandle, HWND_MESSAGE);

// Change back

SetParent(newParent, currentHandle);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the parameters reversed. To restore the original parent you need:

```
SetParent(currentHandle, newParent);
```

Remember that in both cases you are changing the parent of your window. So the first parameter to `SetParent` must the same both times.

Part of the problem is that your variables are poorly named. I would name them like this:

```
// convert to message only
HWND previousParent = SetParent(window, HWND_MESSAGE);

// restore parent
SetParent(window, previousParent);
```